# laravel 5.3 route throwing 404

Tags: laravel

I'm trying this in Laravel 5.3 and it doesn't work am I missing something

in routes/web.php

```
Route::resource('system/suppliers/', 'System\Suppliers\MainController',['names'=>[

    'edit'=>'suppliers.edit',
    'index'=>'suppliers.index',
    'create'=>'suppliers.create',
    'store'=>'suppliers.store',
    'destroy'=>'suppliers.destroy',
    'update'=>'suppliers.update',
    'show'=>'suppliers.show'

]]);

Route::resource('system/suppliers/payments', 'System\Suppliers\PaymentsController',['names'=>[

    'index'=>'suppliers.payments.index',
    'create'=>'suppliers.payments.create',
    'store'=>'suppliers.payments.store',
    'edit'=>'suppliers.payments.edit',
    'destroy'=>'suppliers.payments.destroy',
    'update'=>'suppliers.payments.update',
    'show'=>'suppliers.payments.show'

]]);
```

when i try to edit a supplier it gives me a 404 
www.myurl.com/system/suppliers/2

ive tried as a route group and without(as above)

Comment: try that `www.myurl.com/system/suppliers/2/edit`

Comment: What do you get from `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: `Route::resource('system.suppliers', 'MainController');` and `Route::resource('system.suppliers.payments', 'PaymentsController');` should do it..

using Route::resource, you don't have to specify the index, create, etc.

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN sorry that didn't work

Comment: @user3253002 He is giving names to those routes... why shouldn't he specify index, create etc....?

Comment: @sansible Can you please try interchanging the position of the resource routes, I believe this is happening because of the payments route overwriting show function of suppliers. Basically, can you try putting `system/suppliers/payments` resource route before `system/suppliers`. Waiting for your reply :)

Comment: Just throwing it out there, have you changed something in your HTACCESS file? Since the default URL format of Laravel is "localhost/<project_name>/public/<defined_route>"

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the slashes "\" with "/"

```
Route::resource('system/suppliers/', 'System/Suppliers/MainController',['names'=>[

    'edit'=>'suppliers.edit',
    'index'=>'suppliers.index',
    'create'=>'suppliers.create',
    'store'=>'suppliers.store',
    'destroy'=>'suppliers.destroy',
    'update'=>'suppliers.update',
    'show'=>'suppliers.show'

]]);
```